# Manga where a succubus/vampire meets human guy

Tags: story-identification, vampire, manga

This is a manga that I just read recently, but forgot the title, where a succubus/vampire meets human guy.

I remember the ending, where the guy died because of the excessive energy being sucked by the girl, and at the very end of the story is that there is somehow a wilted ring on her hand and she is on her bed lying down.

Comment: This is a story-identification question about a "succubus" or "vampire", which sounds fantastical. Hence, I have migrated it here.

Comment: Up until you said he died, I was thinking Rosario + Vampire: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosario_%2B_Vampire

Comment: is this comic title SFW or NSFW ?

Comment: In the Rosario Vampire Manga didn´t the human died out of this reason and got revived as a ghoul ? In the anime it was completly removed and rinsed softly.